# Pipe OpenCV and PyAudio to ffmpeg streaming youtube rtmp from python

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, stream, pyaudio

How can I pipe openCV and PyAudio to ffmpeg streaming youtube rtmp from python.
The error message shows as following:
No such filter: 'pipe:1'
pipe:1: Invalid argument

Here is my code:

## Import module

```
import cv2
import subprocess
import pyaudio
```

## Audio

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')
for i in range(0, numdevices):
        if (p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
            print("Input Device id ", i, " - ", p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name'))

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

# Stream Audio data here
# data = stream.read(CHUNK)
```

## Video

```
rtmp = r'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps = 30
```

## command param here

```
command = ['ffmpeg',
           '-y',
           '-f', 'rawvideo',
           '-pixel_format', 'bgr24',
           '-video_size', "{}x{}".format(width, height),
           '-framerate', str(fps),
           '-i', 'pipe:0',
           '-re',
           '-f', 'lavfi',
           '-i', 'pipe:1',
           '-c:v', 'libx264',
           '-c:a', 'aac',
           '-vf', 'format=yuv420p',
           '-f', 'flv',
           rtmp]
```

## Create subprocess to ffmpeg command

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE
)
while cap.isOpened():
    success, frame = cap.read()
    if success:
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        pipe.stdin.write(frame.tostring())
        pipe.stdin.write(stream.read(CHUNK))
```

## Audio Stop

```
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

## Video Stop

```
cap.release()
pipe.terminate()
```

Thanks

Comment: At first try the command manually on the shell and try/check from there, is far easier...

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#toc-pipe): `pipe:[number]` number is the number corresponding to the file descriptor of the pipe (e.g. **0** for **stdin**, **1** for **stdout**, **2** for **stderr**). I don't think you can use: `'-i', 'pipe:1'`.

Comment: Thanks, so I make a mistake for pipe:1. If I want to make two input(video & audio), I need to use 0 for stdin(video) and create another pipe for second input(audio). If this code is running on windows base, how to create a named pipe and stream bytes in pipe?

Comment: so, how to make the pipe?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have successfully used CreateNamePipe to create for video and use stdin for audio.

```
PIPE_NAME = r'\\.\pipe\VideoPipe'

video_pipe = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(
    PIPE_NAME,
    win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,
    win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | win32pipe.PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | win32pipe.PIPE_WAIT,
    1, 65536, 65536,
    0,
    None)
```